# angular CDK drag & drop: nested droplist

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to build a [demo app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odppkg-hcwe66) where I can plan students and their desks. When a classroom has too many desks I can put them in another classroom. I can then plan the students on said desks. I'm using `cdkDropListGroup` because the amount of classrooms is a dynamic.

When I drop a desk with students on the 'not assigned' student list, the desk remains in the class room, but the students drop into the list as expected. 
However when I try to drop the students on the desks, the predicate, which only allows products to be dropped in the list, doesn't allow them. When I remove the predicate however, the student are dropped in the classrooms list instead of the desks...

**Dropping desks with students works properly:**

[image: Proper functioning of the app]

**Dropping students on desks fails:**

[image: Failing part]

*I need help with dropping the students specifically on the desks instead of the classrooms, causing dropStudent to trigger.*

I thought raising the container for the desks to a higher Z-Index might help but that didn't work.

references:

- [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)
- [similar question stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106125/drop-items-in-nested-droplists-angular-7-material-cdk)
- [Stackblitz example where I'm stuck](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odppkg-hcwe66)

Comment: You can use `cdkDropListConnectedTo` property like `[cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[unassignedStudents]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `cdkDropListConnectedTo` option on the not assigned students lists, and add all instances of the desk lists. That's beacuse the `CdkDropListGroup` only looks at sibling lists, not at children:

You need to add a template reference to your desk droplist, so you can query this in your component ts, or you can use the a string of IDs. I think the template reference is more versatile, but for the sake of example I'll use the ids:

```
<div cdkDropList 
      id="{{studentList.listName}}" 
      [cdkDropListData]="studentList.student"
      class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="returnStudent($event)"
      [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="userReturnPredicate"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="desks">
  <div  *ngFor="let person of studentList.student"
        class="example-box" 
        cdkDrag
        [cdkDragData]="person">
    {{person.userName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the `cdkDropListConnectedTo` has `desks` binded. In your component you can define desks like this:

```
desks: string[] = [];

this.desks = this.projectLists.map(
  (list) => list.products.map((product) => product.productName)
).flat(2);
```

To make it work with `ViewChildren`, you need something like this in your `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.deskLists.changes.pipe(
    startWith(true),
    tap(() => {
      this.desks = this.deskLists.toArray();
      this.cd.markForCheck();
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }),
  ).subscribe();
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odppkg-n89x4h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the quick, full answer, with working example and explanation! I didn't know I could assign a String[] to `cdkDropListConnectedTo`

Comment: Seems that after I move a desk, I can't drop a student anymore to that specific desk. When I add `
    this.desks = this.deskLists.toArray();
    this.cd.markForCheck();
    this.cd.detectChanges();` to `dropStudent`, it'll work after dropping one student on another desk

Comment: @JamesD Right, i noticed the string id list wasn't working anymore, so the 'working example' in the link actually uses the desklists with `ViewChildren`. It's the best option anyways :)/ O

Comment: @JamesD I've updated my answer with a better way to handle changes in the lists. This will make sure the desks get updated. You can also use this as an observable without the subscribe, and use the `async` pipe in your template

Comment: Found the answer to my secondary question when moving a desk. By adding `setTimeout(() =>{ this.desks = this.deskLists.toArray();}, 0);` at the end of the `drop` function everything works perfectly, even after moving desks

Comment: @JamesD right, that would be the same as actually listening to changes on the QueryList :) which I think it's a bit more clean than using setTimeout

Comment: Yeah your solution is definitly cleaner! Thanks!

Comment: @JamesD You're welcome. It needs the `startWith(true)`, because otherwise it does not got triggered when the component is loaded, just fyi :D